# remove \r\n while reading a file into stl vector

Tags: c++, stl

I am using following C++ stl construct to read the file into `vector of characters`

```
std::ifstream testFile(inFileName, std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

But this also read `\r\n` into the vector.

Is there any way to avoid reading `\r\n` or delete after reading

Comment: I suppose you don't want to use `istream_iterator<char>` because of performance reasons?

Comment: Using `std::istream_iterator<char>` either eats all spaces or it doesn't make any difference to end of line sequences (depending on `std::ios_base::skipws` being set or not).

Comment: Do you want to get rid of all '\r' and '\n' or do you want to keep line breaks by converting the '\r\n' sequence into a single '\n'?

Comment: @Dietmar I tested [this code](http://pastebin.com/2wF6LSXd) with a file like this `abc\r\n` (5B) and the resulting file is `abc\n` (4B). So it does make a difference if you write back in binary mode?

Comment: @jrok: On a UNIX system? It works like this on Windows but on UNIX I would be surprised if any conversion were done. If you tested it on a UNIX system I'd be intetested in which system you used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you input file is generated on the same platform as you are reading it on.
Then you can convert the LTS (in this case it looks like '\r\n') to a '\n' simply by opening the file in text mode:

```
std::ifstream testFile(inFileName);
```

You can remove specific characters by using the `remove_copy` algorithm:

```
std::vector<char> fileContents;


// Copy all elements that are not '\n'
std::remove_copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile),   // src begin
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),           // src end
                 std::back_inserter(fileContents),           // dst begin
                '\n');                                       // element to remove
```

If you need to remove more than one type of character you need to create a functor and use `remove_copy_if` algorithm:

```
struct DelNLorCR
{
    bool operator()(char x) const {return x=='\n' || x=='\r';}
};
std::remove_copy_if(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile),   // src begin
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),           // src end
                    std::back_inserter(fileContents),           // dst begin
                    DelNLorCR());                               // functor describing bad characters
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting following error with this.   error C2780: '_OutTy *std::remove_copy_if(_InIt,_InIt,_OutTy (&)[_OutSize],_Pr)' : expects 4 arguments - 1 provided
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm(1757) : see declaration of 'std::remove_copy_if'
1>error C2780: '_OutIt std::remove_copy_if(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,_Pr)' : expects 4 arguments - 1 provided
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm(1741) : see declaration of 'std::remove_copy_if'

Comment: @Avinash: Fixed. There was an extra `)` at `<char>(testFile))<- there`

Answer (score 1):

Passing the flag `ios::binary` when you create a stream object tells the stream object not to translate newlines or any other characters that get special encodings when written to or read from a stream. So when you write a file that has newlines in binary mode you get whatever the system uses for a newline. On Windows that's a two-byte sequence, `0x0A`, `0x0D`. If you don't want to see those two bytes, open the stream in text mode, i.e., don't use `ios::binary`. If you do that, you'll get single-character newlines.

And note that it's only coincidence that a '\n' character in a text file gets written as two bytes that correspond to the characters '\r' and '\n'. There is no inherent connection between those character escapes and the bytes that get written, which is why I was careful to refere to `0x0A` and `0x0D`.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the `\r\n` to `\n` conversion isn't done on all systems, even if `std::ios_base::binary` isn't used as an opening flag.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Technically in text mode the conversion from  '\n' to the LTS (Line Termination Sequence) and back is automatic on all platforms. The problem is that LTS is platform specific (ie different platforms have different sequences) and thus a file generated on one platform may not be compatible with another platform. Assuming the file is from the same platform the file will be compatible and the conversion will be done correctly (in text mode).

Comment: @LokiAstari: The conversion done during reading and writing is platform specific. If the conversion is done during writing it needs to be done during reading. If you have a file with `\r\n` on a UNIX system (e.g. because it was created on Windows), you won't get any conversion during reading.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: That is what I said (but more accurately). The conversion is always done.